# How do I limit the posts returned based on custom meta?

Tags: php, wordpress

This retrieves the the posts but does not limit the number of posts returned. How do I put limit on it?

```
// Query Args
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'category_name' => 'payment',
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'key' => 'payment_club',
                    'value' => $current_user->user_login,
            )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category_name' => 'payment',
        'meta_query' => array( array(
                             'key' => 'payment_club',
                             'value' => $current_user->user_login
                           )
                       )
    );
```

I think posts_per_page has to be an integer

Comment: +1 posts_per_page should be an int. Also, 'meta_query' takes an array of arrays, so to be completely valid your 'key' and 'value' need to be inside another array. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: @JacobChappell, good catch. I saw he said it was working so I didn't payed attention to that.